# With jQuery, how to trigger and event that is handled by another version of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `jQuery`, I would like to trigger a `keypress` event where the event is handled by another version of `jQuery`.

```
jQuery2 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$(function(){
    $("#fff").keypress(function(event) { 
        if (event.which == 13) { alert('jQuery'); } 
    });
    jQuery2('#fff').trigger(jQuery2.Event("keypress",{keyCode:13, which:13}));

});
```

Note that the handler is defined with `$` while the event is triggered with `jQuery2`.

Here is a demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSHU2/).
The handler code doesn't run!

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.trigger` function only traverses event handlers that were registered with jQuery.

Instead, use [Native DOM event creation and triggering functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) - your event should then be caught regardless of which jQuery instance registered it:

```
var ev = new Event('keypress');
ev.keycode = 13;
ev.which = 13;

document.getElementById('fff').dispatchEvent(ev);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/b9mCL/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is since `$` and `jQuery2` are two different wrappers, the objects they select are different, too. That is why event does not get triggered. You can cache the selected object in a variable and then raise events:

```
    var $input = $("#fff");
    $input.keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            alert('jQuery');
        }
    });
    $input.trigger(jQuery2.Event("keypress", {
        keyCode: 13,
        which: 13
    }));
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vSHU2/2/)

Comment: In my real-life scenario, I don't have access to the first jQuery version.